# PowerBI Slider to prompt refresh

Tags: sql-server, variables, slider, refresh, powerbi

I want to use a slider filter for time t1 and t2 on my visualization. I want t1, and t2 to be parameters in my query to SQL Server. I want the query to refresh after each committed slider move with the new t1 and t2 values. Is this interactivity possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, nothing in the front end of Power BI can force the backend to do anything.

I did find [a suggestion](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17221487-create-a-parameter-slicer-that-refreshes-queries-o) on the ideas.powerbi.com site that seems to match with what you want. You can go give it a vote and maybe they'll add it down the road.